# OpenCV Writing Fixed Number Of Frames To A Video File Results In Wrong Video Lenth

Tags: python, opencv

In Python I have a fixed list of 1000 frame images, when I send these frames to the VideoWriter at `fps=100` the resulting video is only 6 seconds long.

Should not this video be exactly 10 seconds? or is there something I am missing?

Attached below is the constructor for the VideoWriter

```
fourcc = cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc(*'DIVX')
video = cv2.VideoWriter(
    'test-' + str(time.time()) + '.mp4',
    fourcc,
    float(100),
    (1920, 1200)
)
```

Comment: are all frames of the same shape and dtype? they must match what you promised to VideoCapture? (uint8, 3-channel)

Comment: @ChristophRackwitz to my knowledge they are.
normally i just pass the size of the frame to the video writer via variable, but i hard coded it in the post to make it clearer